Using VBA to mailmerge non-linear table in MS WORD with an excel table
I want to mailmerge a word document containing unlinear table from Microsoft word with an excel table. The word and excel documents contains table with 3 parameters to mailmerge named "Exigence", "NC" and "Commentaire" Each entries in the excel table must give for result a new table in the same word document with value from excel table and leap line between each table so the code must allow user to positioning the entries in the word table because the "NC" and "Exigences" will mailmerge in the same cell in word document. The code must also let the user choose the excel file location via a dialog box. I also precise that the parameters "Commentaire" has a long text which can print in one page so be aware of that when you will chose the type for this variable.
The problem with this code is that the result is a word doc with the duplicate table without the values from the excel table for each values, Someone to help me.
CODE I PRODUCE :
Sub MailMergeFromExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Dim xlFilePath As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim tbl As Word.Table
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim newTable As Word.Table
Dim cell As Word.Cell
Dim cellText As String

' Initialize Word Application
Set wdApp = Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

' Initialize Excel Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

' Open file dialog to select Excel file
Set dlgOpen = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

dlgOpen.Title = "Select the Excel File"
dlgOpen.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1

If dlgOpen.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub ' User canceled

xlFilePath = dlgOpen.SelectedItems(1)

' Open the selected Excel file
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFilePath)
Set xlWs = xlWb.Sheets(1)

' Loop through each row in the Excel table
For i = 2 To xlWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Assuming first row is headers

' Find the template table
Set tbl = wdDoc.Tables(1) ' Assumes the template table is the first table in the document

' Copy the template table
tbl.Range.Copy

' Insert a new table based on the template
Set rng = wdDoc.Range
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.InsertParagraphAfter
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.Paste
Set newTable = wdDoc.Tables(wdDoc.Tables.Count)

' Replace placeholders with Excel data
For Each cell In newTable.Range.Cells

cellText = cell.Range.Text
cellText = Replace(cellText, Chr(13) & Chr(7), "") ' Remove end of cell marker

Select Case cellText
Case "{Exigence}"
cell.Range.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 1).Value ' Assuming "Exigence" is in column A
Case "{NC}"
cell.Range.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 2).Value ' Assuming "NC" is in column B
Case "{Commentaire}"
cell.Range.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 3).Value ' Assuming "Commentaire" is in column C
Case Else
Debug.Print "Placeholder not found: " & cellText
End Select
Next cell

' Add a line break after the table
newTable.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
newTable.Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

Next i

' Cleanup
xlWb.Close False
xlApp.Quit
Set xlWs = Nothing
Set xlWb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Excel table sample

Word table Example


When posting code for review, please don't double-space every line (fixed) and please indent your code (please fix!) so it's more easily read.

Except for prompting for and opening the data source and actually initiating the merge , you may be able to do this as a regular mailmerge by putting any text/material that is outside your "template" in { IF } fields along the lines of { IF { MERGESEQ }  = 1 "your text and graphics" "" } and using normal { MERGEFIELD } fields in the table, then doing a Directory merge. Difficult to tell from the description!

Here's some sample code for a different approach using Find to locate all placeholder tags ({sometexthere}) in any given Range and return a collection of Ranges which you can then process.
This allows you to combine multiple tags in a single cell if needed, instead of needing the full cell text to match the tag.
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim col As Collection, el, doc as Word.Document
    
    Set doc = ThisDocument 
    Set col = GetTags(doc.Tables(2).Range)  'find all placeholders in Table#2
    
    For Each el In col        'loop over returned ranges
        Select Case el.Text
            Case "{A}": el.Text = "this was A"
            Case "{B}": el.Text = "this was B"
            Case "{C}": el.Text = "this was C"
        End Select
    Next el
    
End Sub


'Return a collection of all Word ranges with text like `{*}`
'   within range `rng`
Function GetTags(rng As Word.Range) As Collection
    Set GetTags = New Collection
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\{*\}" 'need to escape {} with backslash...
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        Do While .Execute
            GetTags.Add rng.Duplicate 'save this range...
        Loop
    End With
End Function

Result:

Your code updated:
Sub MailMergeFromExcel()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWb As Excel.Workbook, xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog, txt As String
    Dim xlFilePath As String, i As Integer, allTags As Collection, rng
    Dim tbl As Word.Table, newTable As Word.Table
    
    Set wdApp = Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument
    
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set dlgOpen = xlApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    dlgOpen.Title = "Select the Excel File"
    dlgOpen.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1
    If dlgOpen.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub ' User canceled
    
    xlFilePath = dlgOpen.SelectedItems(1)
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlFilePath) ' Open the selected Excel file
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Loop through each row in the Excel table
    For i = 2 To xlWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Assuming first row is headers
    
        Set tbl = wdDoc.Tables(1) 'template table is the first table in the document
        tbl.Range.Copy
        Set rng = wdDoc.Range     'Insert a new table based on the template
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rng.InsertParagraphAfter
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rng.Paste
        Set newTable = wdDoc.Tables(wdDoc.Tables.Count)
        
        Set allTags = GetTags(newTable.Range) 'find all tags in new table
        For Each rng In allTags
            txt = rng.Text
            Select Case txt
                Case "{Exigence}": rng.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 1).Value
                Case "{NC}": rng.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 2).Value
                Case "{Commentaire}": rng.Text = xlWs.Cells(i, 3).Value
                Case Else: MsgBox "Placeholder '" & txt & "' not matched!", vbExclamation
            End Select
        Next rng
        
        newTable.Range.InsertParagraphAfter ' Add a line break after the table
        newTable.Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    
    Next i
    
    xlWb.Close False ' Cleanup
    xlApp.Quit
    
End Sub

